# Foreach в таблицу на vue

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите как создать таблицу в 3 колонки по 3 значения из массива

В конечном счете должно получится что то типа этого

```
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>2000 грн. до 30.05.2020</td>
                                <td>2000 грн. до 30.05.2020</td>
                                <td>2000 грн. до 30.05.2020</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2000 грн. до 30.05.2020</td>
                                <td>2000 грн. до 30.05.2020</td>
                                <td>2000 грн. до 30.05.2020</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2000 грн. до 30.05.2020</td>
                                <td>2000 грн. до 30.05.2020</td>
                                <td>2000 грн. до 30.05.2020</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Вот массив для примера

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "product_id": 16,
    "pay": 2700,
    "day": 0,
    "created_at": "2020-05-17 21:58:59",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-17 21:58:59"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "product_id": 16,
    "pay": 1080,
    "day": 30,
    "created_at": "2020-05-17 21:59:23",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-17 21:59:23"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "product_id": 16,
    "pay": 1080,
    "day": 60,
    "created_at": "2020-05-17 21:59:37",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-17 21:59:37"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "product_id": 16,
    "pay": 1080,
    "day": 90,
    "created_at": "2020-05-17 21:59:55",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-17 21:59:55"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "product_id": 16,
    "pay": 1080,
    "day": 120,
    "created_at": "2020-05-17 22:00:28",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-17 22:00:28"
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "product_id": 16,
    "pay": 1080,
    "day": 150,
    "created_at": "2020-05-17 22:00:49",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-17 22:00:49"
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "product_id": 16,
    "pay": 1080,
    "day": 180,
    "created_at": "2020-05-17 22:01:00",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-17 22:01:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "product_id": 16,
    "pay": 1080,
    "day": 210,
    "created_at": "2020-05-17 22:01:19",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-17 22:01:19"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "product_id": 16,
    "pay": 1080,
    "day": 210,
    "created_at": "2020-05-17 22:01:19",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-17 22:01:19"
  }
]
```

Comment: Где ваша реализация и попытки решения задачи?

Comment: К сожалению даже попытки решения я не  знаю

Comment: Тогда советую сделать попытки решения, а пока я голосую за закрытие

Comment: Изменил как пример конечной таблицы

Comment: Я хоть что-то сделал. А тут мне упрёки. Удаляю ответ пиши сам.

Comment: как вариант разбейте свой исходный массив на массив с нужным кол-ом элементов и выведите это в колонки таблицы

Comment: Aziz Umarov ты читай суть вопроса прежде чем писать ответ лишь бы как

Comment: Попробуйте v-for. В документации он подробно описан.